# Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : numbers of columns of arguments do not match after storing variable as a factor

Tags: r, linear-regression, categorical-data, rbind, psych

I am running a hierarchical regression in R. When I run the following code to change my categorical variable to be stored as a factor, it causes my models to change.

```
#Check to see if Frame is stored as a factor (categorical variable)
is.factor(dat$Frame)
#Frame is not stored categorically
#Change Frame to a factor
dat$Frame <- as.factor(dat$Frame)
```

If I do not run the above code, my models are both lists of 12. When I do run the above code, Model 2 becomes a list of 13, meaning I get an error when I run the following code:

```
apa.reg.table(Model1, Model2, filename="Table1_APA.doc", 
table.number=1)

Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

The code I am using for my models are as follows:

```
Model1 <- lm(data = dat, Memory ~ Word_Count) 
Model2 = lm(data = dat, Memory ~ Word_Count + Frame)
```

Please tell me why changing Frame to a factor causes the number of columns in Model 2 to change.

Comment: If you use a factor, the `lm` model object is a list that now contains a list called `contrasts` that lists the contrasts for your factor. I have the same problem. Still trying to figure it out.